# Constructor explanation C#

Tags: c#, class, constructor

I am little confused with constructor use so can someone please explain me on simple example. I give example of a simple code and in it I don't know why to use constructor instead of the way I am using.

I made class for calculation

```
public class Calculation
{
    private double a;
    private double b;
    private double c;
    private double d;
    private double e;

    public Calculation ()
    {

    }

    public double e (double a,double b,double c,double d)
    {
        e = (a * 10) / (b * c * d);
        return e;
    }
}
```

Now I made an instance of this class in my windows form

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Calculation example;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        example = new Calculation();
    }

    private double A = 200;
    private double B = 45;
    private double C = 55;
    private double D = 20;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string E = (example.e(A, B, C, D).ToString());
        label1.Text = E;
    }
```

Whats are the advantages and disadvantages of this method that I used? Is there more efficient way to do this with the constructor?
I am confused because everything is public either way, you can't instantiate private class and private constructor.

Comment: There is no need for an empty constructor in your case. Constructors are mostly used to initialize variables. On top of that you don't need those readonly private members either.

Comment: First and foremost, you should provide an example which actually compiles... `_racunskiMiSd` and `e` are undefined variables in function `e`.

Comment: Your question is too broad and vague. What do you mean by *"advantage and disadvantages of this method"*? What method, using a constructor?

Comment: lucas, sorry there was something copied wrong.. there should be e.. but that is not what i meant

Comment: yuval is this correct way?? if it is, what's the use of constructors?

Comment: Well... `e` is *still* undefined in your edited code. :-) As for your class, drop all its fields (you don't use them), drop the constructor, define it as `public static class Calculation`, and make the `e` function `static`, then call it as `Calculation.e` (and drop `example = new Calculation();` and the `example` field too).

Comment: Couldn't you just [read the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ace5hbzh.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use a constructor with parameters instead of a method with parameters when you want to create an instance of your class and at the same time set its internal state.

Constructors have the task of initializing the object's data members and leaving the resulting object in a valid state.

You should learn more about concepts of OOP (object-oriented programming). Start by reading about Methods, Classes, Constructors, Setters and Getters to learn the basics then go from there.